# MongoDB Compass installation do not work for windows

Tags: mongodb-compass

When I try to install it, the loading window pops up, I see the progress bar and then the window disappears and nothing happens.

When I go to "Add or remove programs" in windows, I see this:
[image]

Does anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue be re-install MongoDB with Compass together (In the past it didn't work, so I had to install them one by one. Now it works).

Answer (score 4):

You can navigate to directory with path `C:\Program Files (x86)\MongoDB Compass Community Installer\` and execute the file `MongoDBCompassCommunity.exe`

Compass will then install itself and you can find the installed files under directory `C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\MongoDBCompassCommunity`